# python 3.x code not adding all 'for' loop total price values and only using the total price of the last input

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner to using python and I was trying to create a program in pyscripter to be a basic ordering menu for a food shop. I have gotten most of what I want working but I have a problem with the program not adding the total_price at the end. It only adds the price of the last item I ordered and the other items ordered will have a value of 0.

```
import sys
print("Welcome to Terry's Restaurant!")

num_items=int(input("Please enter 1-4 items to be ordered, type 0 to cancel order: "))
print("""Please choose items from :

    1. Macaroni Pizza
    2. Garlic Bread
    3. Coca Cola
    4. Onion Rings
    5. Fries
    0. To exit shop/cancel order""")

#for loop to ask for input depending on the number the user types for num_items
#each order will ask for quantity and prints a total price

for num_items in range (num_items):
    order=input("\nPlease enter your desired item using 1-5: ")
    if order == "1":
        item1 = "Macaroni Pizza"
        price1 = 15
        quantity1 =int(input("How many would you like? "))
        total1 =quantity1 * price1
        print (quantity1, item1 ,"$",total1)
    else:
        total1=0
    if order == "2":
        item2= "Garlic Bread"
        price2 = 6
        quantity2 =int(input("How many would you like? "))
        total2 = quantity2 * price2
        print (quantity2, item2,"$",total2)
    else:
        total2=0
    if order == "3":
        item3 = "Coca Cola"
        price3 = 4
        quantity3 = int(input("How many would you like? "))
        total3 = quantity3 * price3
        print (quantity3, item3,"$",total3)
    else:
        total3=0
    if order == "4":
        item4 = "Onion Rings"
        price4 = 4
        quantity4 = int(input("How many would you like? "))
        total4 = quantity4 * price4
        print (quantity4, item4,"$",total4)
    else:
        total4=0
    if order == "5":
        item5 = "Fries"
        price5 = 4
        quantity5 = int(input("How many would you like? "))
        total5 = quantity5 * price5
        print (quantity5, item5,"$",total5)
    else:
        total5=0
    if order == "0":
        sys.exit()
        print("Cancelling Order. Thank you come again")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid item")

#total_price to add the total prices for each item ordered
total_price = total1, total2, total3, total4, total5
print("\nYour order total is $", total_price)
```

Comment: You explicitly reset `totalX = 0` in any round where a value wasn't entered for that item - if that's not the behaviour you want, don't do that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah I see what you mean. before having this problem I had a problem of it trying to add a null value when someone ordered something like 2 items and there was no order for items 3,4,5. Would there be a better way to do the addition?

Comment: I've worked it out now. I set default values before the loop to each totalX=0 and removed the totalX=0 in the loop. It stops the totalX from becoming a null value if there is no item selected      `total1 = 0
total2 = 0
total3 = 0
total4 = 0
total5 = 0`